cant get nvidia display detected on dell poweredge r320
I can't get the Nvidia GPU to detect a display for the life of me but it works fine on Windows
I do have two VGA-compatible controllers

Nvidia GT 710 (Nvidia driver 470)
Matrox G200eR2 (the only working display)

lspci shows both GPUs in the system

I have already tried disabling the Matrox in the bios but I got no display within Ubuntu.
Also, I have tried the server drivers and the x.org server driver with no luck.

